# WooCommerce: How to exclude a specific page in a hooked action

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, hook-woocommerce

This code works perfectly except I'm trying to determine how to EXCLUDE the main shop page from being included in the action. This hook adds the HTML code to all archive-type pages including the main shop page. Given this is a link back to the shop page, it should be excluded on the shop page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function add_back_to_catalog_category() { 
    ?>
    <div><br><p class="button-catalog"><a href="/shop/">Back to Catalog - All Products</a></p></div><?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'add_back_to_catalog_category' );
```

[Visual reference to `woocommerce_after_shop_loop` action hook.](https://hooks.wpdesk.org/shop/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WooCommerce conditional tag [`is_shop()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-4) like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'add_back_to_catalog_category' );
function add_back_to_catalog_category() { 
    // Not on shop page
    if( ! is_shop() ) {
        printf( '<div><br><p class="button-catalog"><a href="%s">%s</a></p></div>', 
            get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ), 
            __("Back to Catalog - All Products", "your-text-domain") 
        );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Getting error and won't save in functions.php ... Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 52 of file wp-content/themes/pro-child/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: Line 52 includes 'if( ! is_shop() } {'